# What is &ff in the SDL Mix_HookMusic clarification in documentation

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to write my own custom playback function and was looking at the documentation for SDL `Mix_HookMusic` function when I came across the `&ff`. What does this refer to? Thank you in advance!

```
// make a music play function
// it expects udata to be a pointer to an int

void myMusicPlayer(void *udata, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
    int i, pos=*(int*)udata;

    // fill buffer with...uh...music...
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        stream[i]=(i+pos)&ff;

    // set udata for next time
    pos+=len;
    *(int*)udata=pos;
}
...
// use myMusicPlayer for playing...uh...music
int music_pos=0;
Mix_HookMusic(myMusicPlayer, &music_pos);
```

Comment: I haven't found it yet, but since `pos` is already a pointer into the data, I'm having difficulty determining what type `(int*)(int*)` would have. Could they have intended `*(i+pos)`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin If so, what is `ff`? I think that was more the question here - why wouldn't it be a parameter? Is it supposed to be a global just named `ff`?

Comment: @JohnP What pointers are you talking about? Both `i` and `pos` are `int`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You're right, I misread.  JerryCoffin Fair enough, but if that's the case, that's enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `i` and `pos` are both variables, it looks like in this case, the `&` involved is the bitwise-and operator. At a guess (but with no certainty), `ff` is probably a variable containing the value `0xff`. That means this would take `i+pos`, retrieve the least significant 8 bits, and write that value to `stream[i]` (which makes a degree of sense, since `stream` is a pointer to `Uint8`s, which it's probably fair to assume is a typedef for `unsigned char`.

Comment: That makes sense although I think '&' is the bitwise AND operator. Then the value it's masking with is 0xff.

Comment: What would be the purpose of the mask, clarity? I thought casting to unsigned char would implicitly perform that mask.

Comment: @JohnP: Yes, clarity would be my guess. It is also possible that `ff` actually holds some other value (but clarity seems more likely).

Comment: @avenmia: Oops--yes, and, not or.

Comment: I thought maybe there was some consideration for endianness, but I've never understood when that would be necessary (I assumed it would only be relevant communicating between devices.)

Comment: @JohnP: It's not relevant in any case--either way, you get (what this CPU sees as) the least significant bits.

Comment: In any case? I thought the MSB/LSB would swap between big- and little-endian devices, so each would choose `ff` as `0xff000000` to mask the values coming from the other. Otherwise I don't know when it *would* be relevant. I should probably defer to a question about this specifically...

Comment: @JohnP: Let me try to state my point more explicitly: `(uint8_t)x` and `x & 0xff` will both retain precisely the same 8 bits of `x`. If you want some bits other than those, you'll have to do something else.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That was my understanding from my first comment. Anything explicitly differentiated from my expectations raises my hackles ever since the 'most ambiguous parse' in C++; endianness was the only thing I could think of that would prompt someone to make an alias for a mask that's (a) constant, (b) a no-op, (c) shorter by two keystrokes, and as Avenmia noticed, (d) undocumented. Doesn't mean it was a good explanation for the context, just the best I could come up with.